Adjust single page to fit wide table
I have a wide table I would like to fit on a single page in my document.
However, the default document is too narrow.
Ideally I would like to have one page where the table is perfectly fitted into the center.
I have seen other approaches that scale the table size, but I would like to keep it as is.
I tried a few approaches the one that got me the farthest is:
\newlength{\classpageheight} 
\setlength{\classpageheight}{\pdfpageheight}

\newlength{\classpagewidth} 
\setlength{\classpagewidth}{\pdfpagewidth}

\eject \pdfpagewidth=20in \pdfpageheight=8in

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{...}
\label{table:correlation}

\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccccccc}
%... my content
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\eject \pdfpagewidth=\classpagewidth \pdfpageheight=\classpageheight


This changes my page size, and my table is nicely visible. However, it is not centered, and the caption is somewhere on the left side of the page.
While I'm fine with manually setting the page size (20in, 8in) is there a way to find the table dimensions and then adjust the page size automatically?
The other approach I tried is:
\afterpage{%
  \clearpage
  \newgeometry{paperwidth=20in, paperheight=8in, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 \\
      \hline
      Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data 4 & Data 5 \\
      Data 6 & Data 7 & Data 8 & Data 9 & Data 10 \\
      % Add more rows as needed
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \restoregeometry
  \clearpage
}

but this does not even change my page size, and my table is cut of.

You can create a single landscape page using pdflscape.,  It will look like a wide page, except the headers and footers will be sideways.

thanks for the suggestion, but my table is still too wide for the page

It is not necessary to change the page size. Just use \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{tabular} ...\end{tabular}}. If it doesn't fit on the paper then you have to redesign the table. For example with  \usepackage{tabularx} and \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}...\end{tabularx}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\newgeometry{margin=5mm}
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}\centering
\leavevmode\vfill
\rule{26cm}{15cm} % your wide table
\vfill
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{document}


